# Speed up a query for a large table

Tags: mysql, performance, spatial

I'm making an app with geolocation so i have a cities table with more than 2 millions records and i want to get the nearest record to a defined latitude and longitude having a index on both columns. The code realizes what i want but it takes between 3 and 4 seconds to achieve.

I've tried to put index on latitude and longitude, and longitude only. I've also tried to put separately index on latitude and longitude.

```
SELECT * FROM Cities 
ORDER BY ABS(someLatitude - latitude) ASC, ABS(someLongitude - longitude) ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

I expect the code execute in less than a second. What can i do?

Comment: Have you looked into cacheing these queries? Ultimately if you're already indexing caching is the next step in my opinion. I'd look into memcached.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know how to cache records in MySQL. The query above will be called the first page a user visite.

Comment: Caching Queries using memcached is actually super easy and they have great documentation thats super easy to understand.

Comment: Let me take a look at memcached.

Comment: The query is taking the same seconds with or without indexes to achieved

Comment: Can you show us the 'create table' and how did you crate that index? Is it a spatial index?

Comment: Caching is useless if "someLat and some Long" change with every query.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY ABS(someLatitude - latitude) ASC,
         ABS(someLongitude - longitude) ASC
```

WTF?  That will collect all the cities with very similar latitudes together -- even those from the other side of the globe!

```
mysql> SELECT country, city, lat, lng FROM `cities`
       WHERE population > 0
       ORDER BY ABS(lat - 36) ASC,
                ABS(lng - 0) ASC LIMIT 10;
+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
| country | city      | lat     | lng      |
+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
| jp      | Okegawa   |      36 |  139.557 |
| us      | Sapulpa   | 35.9986 | -96.1139 |
| us      | Avenal    | 36.0042 | -120.128 |
| cn      | Zhucheng  | 35.9947 |  119.397 |
| us      | Durham    | 35.9939 | -78.8989 |
| us      | Espanola  | 35.9911 |  -106.08 |
| jp      | Chichibu  | 35.9903 |  139.076 |
| us      | Oak Ridge | 36.0103 | -84.2697 |
| ir      | Baneh     | 35.9894 |  45.8953 |
| es      | Tarifa    | 36.0125 | -5.60556 |
+---------+-----------+---------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.90 sec)
```

Notice that cities in Japan, US, China, Ireland, and Spain are "near" each other based on that `ORDER BY`.  (My list has 3M cities, many with population=0.)

The first optimization is to pick a maximum distance and draw a "bounding box" around the center.  And have an index:

```
    mysql> SELECT country, city, lat, lng FROM `cities` WHERE population > 0
            -> AND lat BETWEEN 36-2 AND 36+2
            -> AND lng BETWEEN -84-3 AND -84+3
            -> LIMIT 10;                                                                                    
        +---------+---------------+---------+----------+
        | country | city          | lat     | lng      |
        +---------+---------------+---------+----------+
        | us      | Gadsden       | 34.0142 | -86.0067 |
        | us      | Cedartown     | 34.0536 |  -85.255 |
        | us      | Acworth       | 34.0658 | -84.6769 |
        | us      | Kennesaw      | 34.0233 | -84.6156 |
        | us      | Woodstock     | 34.1014 | -84.5194 |
        | us      | Mountain Park | 34.0808 | -84.4114 |
        | us      | Roswell       | 34.0231 | -84.3617 |
        | us      | Alpharetta    | 34.0753 | -84.2942 |
        | us      | Duluth        | 34.0028 | -84.1447 |
        | us      | Suwanee       | 34.0514 | -84.0714 |
        +---------+---------------+---------+----------+
```

with `INDEX(lat)` or `INDEX(lng)` or `INDEX(lat,lng)` or `INDEX(lng,lat)`.  (Those indexes are about equally good/bad.  But still it had to look at 257K rows -- namely all the rows in that 4-degree (276-mile or 444-km wide) stripe.

If you don't limit the distance, an index is useless since it will look at all the rows.

It would need some kind of `ORDER BY` clause to compute the distance (either Pythagorean or Great-Circle) to get the "closest".

To get really efficient takes a lot more effort:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng
That discusses, to some depth, why the problem is a tough one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It solved my problem. The other problem is how can i import those 2 millions rows in production ?

Comment: @JosaphatImani - will `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...` work for you?  It can probably load 2M rows in under a minute.